# unable to write lexer to parse this

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am designing my own data format :
-key=value-123

It is "DASH KEY EQUAL IDENTIFIER", problem is, identifier also contain dash, so it eats all characters. Please help

```
DASH        :   '-';
EQUAL       :   '=';
IDENTIFIER  :   [a-zA-Z0-9 -_<>@:\\.@()/]+;
```

thanks
Peter

Comment: If identifiers can contain dashes, then why isn't it correct to lex `value-123` as an identifier? What are the rules determining when `-` is part of the identifier and when it is its own operator?

Comment: I see there's even a space inside the character class of `IDENTIFIER`, which means that `foo 42 bar @@@ ///` will be tokenised as a single `IDENTIFIER`....

Answer (score 1):

This is how ANTLR s work.  If multiple Lexer rules match an input stream of characters, the rule with the longest match will win (when the length matches, the the first rule wins),  Since your `IDENTIFIER` rule includes ‘-‘ but excludes ‘=‘, ANTLR will create the longer token for `IDENTIFIER`.  You won’t be able to get a match for `DASH` unless your input begins with `“-=“` (of course, then there’d be no `IDENTIFIER`).

If you are designing your own format, you could make the choice to disallow “-“ in `IDENTIFIERS` and you should be good to go.

Is this the full picture of what you are attempting to parse, or just a small subset?  If this is the full picture, then you’d be able to easily “parse” this with a REGEX and capture groups.  ANTLR would be overkill.

You could take the following approach if you really have to have a `DASH` in your identifier:

1 - remove the "-" from the `IDENTIFIER` Lexer rule (we'll call that `ID`), and we'll handle the full identifier in an `identifier` parse rule:

```
keyValue  : DASH key=identifier EQUAL val=identifier; 
identifier: ID (DASH ID)+;

DASH  :   '-';
EQUAL :   '=';
ID    :   [a-zA-Z0-9 _<>@:\\.@()/]+;
```

In a listener (or visitor for the `IdentiferCtx` (ex: (enter|exit)Identifer for a listener), you can call cox.getText() for the string of the full identifier rule, and have the full text of your `identifier`